# How to += in SCSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

Does anyone know how to += with SCSS?

Example:

```
.example {
    padding: 2px;
    &:hover {
        padding: current_padding + 3px; // OR
        padding+= 3px                   //... something like this
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get **.example:hover** to have 5px padding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want to in SCSS, but you could achieve the same effect by using variables:

**SCSS**

```
.example {
    $padding: 2px;
    padding: $padding;
    &:hover {
        padding: $padding + 3px;
    }
}
```

**Compiles to**

```
.example { padding: 2px; }
.example:hover { padding: 5px; }
```

See the documentation on [variables](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_) and [number operations](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#number_operations).